# How to generate custom case statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, case

I have problem to write method which generate custom case statement.

My code:

```
nr=68
puts case nr
   when 0..64 then "1"
   when 65..69 then "2"
   when 70..79 then "3"
   when 80..89 then "4"
   when 90..Float::INFINITY then "5"
end
```

I wish to create method that generete this kind of code, for example:

```
puts create_case_range(68,[64,69,79,89])
```

Comment: I accepted @Andy answer. I don't need to generate case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add a bit more detail and context to your question, but if I understand correctly, you can do this without a case statement:

```
def create_case_range(nr, range)
  range = (range | [Float::INFINITY]).sort
  range.index(range.detect { |max| nr <= max }) + 1
end
```

This then gives the result:

```
> create_case_range(68, [64,69,79,89])
=> 2
```

Comment: You are right. In my case I doesn't need to use case statement. I only need to know in which range my value falls. Thank you.